# Как применить CSS свойства только к div (без вложенных элементов)? Почему не работает :not?

Tags: html, css

Я пытаюсь применить анимацию к div, и не применять ее к остальным вложенным в него элементам, используя псевдокласс :not. Но это не работает. Почему и как решить эту проблему не дописывая html?

```css
@keyframes fade-in {
  0% {opacity: 0;} 100% {opacity: 1;}
}

div {
  background: gray;
}

a:link {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 50px;
}

a:visited {
  color: black;
}

:not(a):hover {
  animation: fade-in 1s ease-in-out;
}

p {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="anything">
  <a href="#">ANYTHING</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opacity - свойство, которое скрывает не только блок, но и всё его содержимое. Скрыть блок, не скрывая содержимое, через это свойство нельзя.

Но если div используется для фона ссылки, можно анимацией менять background в значение transparent. Фактически, убирать блок по отдельности (фон, граница и т.д.), не убирая сам блок в целом. Тогда анимация будет выглядеть так:

```css
    @keyframes fade-in {
      0% {background: transparent;} 100% {background: gray;}
    }
```